# filtering a list by 2 keys in react

Tags: reactjs

I would like to have my parent pass some conditions to the child, to filter through a list and return businesses from the list that meet the criteria.
eg.

```
if (service === pub && town === Ipswich) 
return business.name.
```

here is my parent component so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './backgroundimage.jpg';
import './App.css';
import {Child} from './Child.js';

 class Parent extends Component {


   state={
     service: '',
     town: ''
   }

   search (service,town) {
     this.setState({service, town});
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div className="App">
         <Child service={this.state.service} town={this.state.town}/>
       </div>
     );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

ideally I would like to have the input a selection from a number of options in two drop down boxes.

here is my child component so far, where I would like to keep the list and return filtered items back to be rendered in the parent component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Parent} from './App.js';


export class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  state={
    businesses: [
      { service:'Pub',
        town:'rosewood',
        name:'Rising Sun'},

      { service:'Club',
        town:'ipswich',
        name:'Metro'},

      { service:'Club',
        town:'ipswich',
        name:'Switch'},

      { service:'Restaurant'
        town:'ipswich',
        name: 'Dustys'},

      { service:'Pub',
        town:'rosewood',
        name: 'The Royal Hotel'},
    ]
};

check () {
  const {service,town} = this.props;
  return list.find(item => {
    if (service === item.service){return item.name}
    if (town === item.postCode){return item.name}
  })
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{this.check()}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

I want to have the list stored in a child component, so that I can be constantly extending the list as I build bigger, while having it separate from the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `Array.filter()` and then map on the resulting array:

```
render(){
  const {service, town} = this.props
  return(
    <div>
     state.businesses.filter(
       o => o.service === service && o.town === town // filter the array based on some conditions
     ).map(
       item => <p>{item.name}</p> // print the name of the filtered items
     )
    </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: `Array.filter()` has as argument a function that iterates over the array as `Array.map()`. For each element, if the iterator `return true` it will be added to the array otherwise it will be discarded. The result is an array you can go through with `Array.map()``